# Pyspark code is running slower if imported from package in compare to plain code with no imports

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing a peculiar issue while bench-marking my pyspark code for performance.

I am fetching data from kafkadstream, then converting rdd to dataframe and then after some transformations I am saving the spark dataframe in HBase via pheonix.

Below are the stats.

**For development cluster**
*[development cluster][plain code without any package import]*:
number of records: 10
DF creation time: 0.185553 seconds
DF Insert time: 0.511172 seconds

*[development cluster][using common code from package import]*:
Note: package is sent by "--py-files package.zip"
number of records: 10
DF creation time: 2.896647 seconds
DF Insert time: 3.456992 seconds

*[development cluster][using common code from package import]*:
Note: package is installed on each node
number of records: 10
DF creation time: 0.680334 seconds
DF Insert time: 0.831929 seconds


**Now for the production cluster:**
*[production cluster][plain code without any package import]*:
number of records: 10
DF creation time: 0.184458 seconds
DF Insert time: 0.736582 seconds

*[production cluster][using common code from package import]*:
Note: package is sent by "--py-files package.zip"
number of records: 10
DF creation time: 1.925941 seconds
DF Insert time: 2.203001 seconds

*[production cluster][using common code from package import]*:
Note: package is installed on each node
number of records: 10
DF creation time: 1.966830 seconds
DF Insert time: 2.408202 seconds

So in the development cluster when i installed my code on each node and set the PYTHONPATH, it improved the performance and the performance of the code imported from package is almost equal to the plain python code with no imports. But in production this didn't help at all.

for all the above scenarios I have used *--executor-memory 1g --num-executors 1 --executor-cores=1*

I will be highly greatful if some one point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you submit your code with `--py-files` you have to add time to:

- Distribute the zip.
- Unpack the zip in the worker directories.

Additionally if packages are imported, add time to parse and evaluate. Small time differences like this are not particularly surprising and even possible to avoid in this design.

If you want to avoid the problem deploy the packages once on each node.

Comment: I have already tried deploying package on both development and production cluster, but for some reason in production the time is same as passing the package via zip.